# How to count the rows of a filtered table in power bi in a calculated column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to numerate the occurances of a specific column in my table.  The best way I have thought to do this is to count the rows of a filtered table.  So, my WorkOrders table looks like this:

```
WO#  Date       CompCode  Serial#
001  1/1/2021   100       A
001  1/1/2021   101       A
002  1/2/2021   100       B
003  2/1/2021   100       A
004  2/2/2021   100       B
005  2/15/2021  101       A
006  3/1/2021   102       A
006  3/1/2021   100       A
```

I want to create a new column that numerates the occurance on the CompCode by Serial#.  There is no gaurantee that the data is sorted by date.  So, I tried to count the rows of a filtered table using this formula:

```
COMP_OCCURANCE = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(WorkOrders), 
    Serial# = Serial#, 
    Date <= Date, 
    CompCode = CompCode
)
```

I assumed that would work but it does not.  The desired result would look like this:

```
WO#  Date       CompCode  Serial#  COMP_OCCURANCE
001  1/1/2021   100       A        1
001  1/1/2021   101       A        1
002  1/2/2021   100       B        1
003  2/1/2021   100       A        2
004  2/2/2021   100       B        2
005  2/15/2021  101       A        2
006  3/1/2021   102       A        1
006  3/1/2021   100       A        3
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
COMP_OCCURANCE = 
VAR CurrentSerial = WorkOrders[Serial #]
VAR CurrentDate = WorkOrders[Date]
VAR CurrentCode = WorkOrders[CompCode]
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( WorkOrders ),
        WorkOrders[Serial #] = CurrentSerial,
        WorkOrders[CompCode] = CurrentCode,
        WorkOrders[Date] <= CurrentDate,
        REMOVEFILTERS ( WorkOrders )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Screenshot - https://ibb.co/Bj5xrFS

Answer (score 0):

For this type of calculation, you must need to rely on a column for sorting/ordering your data. As you cannot use Date in this case, I think you can go for column "WO#" this case. If this is acceptable, you can try this below measure for your expected output-

```
COMP_OCCURANCE = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(your_table_name[WO#]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[WO#] <= MIN(your_table_name[WO#])
            && your_table_name[CompCode] = MIN(your_table_name[CompCode])
            && your_table_name[Serial#] = MIN(your_table_name[Serial#])
    )
)
```

Output-

[image]